# ¿Como puedo insertar datos con foreach en php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

Tengo un problema a la momento de insertar los datos y es que si se inserta pero si subo dos imágenes se inserta dos veces pero con distintas imágenes este es el código que utilizo para insertar las imágenes

```
foreach ($_FILES['producto']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName) {
                      

                      

                      include"configuracion/config.php";

                      $id_user=$_SESSION['id'];
                      $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
                      $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
                      $precio=$_POST['precio'];

                      $fecha= date("d/m/y");

                      $file_name = $_FILES['producto']['name'][$key];
                      $file_type = $_FILES['producto']['type'][$key];
                      $file_size = $_FILES['producto']['size'][$key];
                      $file_tmp  = $_FILES['producto']['tmp_name'][$key];

                      $ruta=productos."/".$file_name;
                      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $ruta);

                     
                     $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db3 (id_user,Titulo, Descripcion, Precio, Producto, Fecha) values ('$id_user','$titulo','$descripcion','$precio', '$ruta','$fecha')");   
                        
                      echo '<script>setTimeout(function() { location.href="Inicio.php"; }, 500);  </script>';


                    }
```

y esta es la estructura de  mi base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si hago esto  `$conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db3 (id_user,Titulo, Descripcion, Precio, Producto,Producto2, Fecha) values ('$id_user','$titulo','$descripcion','$precio', '$ruta','$ruta','$fecha')");`

no pasa nada ¿**que puedo hacer**?

Comment: Los strings de una comilla (`'''`) no renderizan variables,  de todas maneras creo que hay problemas de seguridad desde `PHP` cuando tu intentas hacer eso, para evitarlo deberias usar una consulta preparada/tratada desde `mysqli` o `PDO` aunque te recomiendo mas las consultas preparadas de PDO,  son mas seguras y actuales.

Comment: Lo otro es que quiza haya incompatibilidad de tipos y por eso la consulta es rechazada,  o lo que estes tratando de hacer es insertar un registro de una llave primaria unica que ya existe.

Comment: lo que veo es que tu sentencia insert lo tienes dentro del `foreach`, por lo que cuando tienes dos o mas imágenes te ejecutará dos o mas veces la instrucción. Pero al ver tu tabla, creo que quieres insertar una imagen en el campo producto y otra en producto1, de ser así tendrías que construir de forma dinámica tu consulta fuera del `foreach`.. aún así, para evitar llenarme de nulos, yo usaría una tabla para la cabecera del producto y otra que contenga las imágenes relacionadas a dicho producto.

Comment: Además del **certero** comentario de @Riven acerca del problema de seguridad, cuando subes varias imágenes o archivos $_FILES los agrupa con subíndices. Por favor repite la prueba y agrega `var_dump($_FILES)` e incluyes en tu pregunta lo que te muestra el volcado de esa variable cuando subes varias imágenes para poder ofrecerte una ayuda significativa.

Comment: Saludos. En base a lo que planteas; tu código está bien al momento de realizar tantos **N** +INSERT* como imágenes recibas; lo que debes revisar es (por así decirlo) si tu tabla (cuyo nombre contiene la variable) en `$tabla_db3` debe tener 1 solo registro sin importar cuantas imagenes sean o 1 por cada imágen (como actualmente está) en caso que debe estar 1 sola vez; entonces lo que tienes que hacer es (digamos) sacar el dato de imagen a otra tabla donde guardes la imagen y la referencia a `$tabla_db3` que corresponda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente, no es la mejor idea tener una columna para cada imagen, porque te va a complicar el mantenimiento de los productos. Normalmente se usa una tabla adicional para relacionar imágenes con productos.

Si aún quieres trabajarlo así, entonces debes crear una variable para cada imagen y llenarla de acuerdo a la cantidad de archivos enviados, realizando la inserción fuera del ciclo:

```
            $id_user=$_SESSION['id'];
            $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
            $descripcion=$_POST['descripcion'];
            $precio=$_POST['precio'];
            $fecha= date("d/m/y");
            // Inicializar variables de imágenes
            $producto = $producto2 = $producto3 = $producto4 = $producto5 = $producto6 = $producto7 = $producto8 = '';
            // Recorres para actualizar variables de imágenes
            foreach ($_FILES['producto']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmpName) {
                  include"configuracion/config.php";


                  $file_name = $_FILES['producto']['name'][$key];
                  $file_type = $_FILES['producto']['type'][$key];
                  $file_size = $_FILES['producto']['size'][$key];
                  $file_tmp  = $_FILES['producto']['tmp_name'][$key];

                  $ruta=productos."/".$file_name;
                  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $ruta);
                  // Qué variable se va a actualizar
                  $var = 'producto';
                  if($key > 0) {
                          // Si es mayor que cero, actualizar nombre de variable
                          // producto2 hasta producto8
                          $var .= ($key + 1);
                  }
                  // Actualizar producto o producto#, usando "Variable variable"
                  $$var = $ruta;
                 
            }
            // Realizas la inserción fuera del ciclo
            $conexion->query("INSERT INTO $tabla_db3 (id_user,Titulo, Descripcion, Precio, Producto, Producto2, Producto3, Producto4, Producto5, Producto6, Producto7, Producto8, Fecha)
                values ('$id_user','$titulo','$descripcion','$precio', '$producto', '$producto2', '$producto3', '$producto4', '$producto5', '$producto6', '$producto7', '$producto8','$fecha')");   
            echo '<script>setTimeout(function() { location.href="Inicio.php"; }, 500);  </script>';
```

Referencia que necesitas leer: [Variables variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php)